# How to disable default screen capturing in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

How to disable default screen capturing in Mac OS X using (Command + Shift + 3) and (Command + Shift + 4). Is there any option in System Preferences for it?

Answer (score 15):

System Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots

[image].

Comment: It's nice that you added the how to above, but you didn't have to be a pompous, self-important, imperious, overbearing, domineering, magisterial, pontifical, sententious, grandiose, affected, pretentious, puffed up, arrogant, vain, haughty, proud, conceited, egotistic, supercilious, condescending, patronizing douche about it.

Comment: From a dedicated Skitch user trying to stop the new Screenshot app in Mojave from taking over, thanks!